# "Insufficient permissions" on google calendar api's acl.list

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I'm getting `Insufficient permissions` when trying to call the acl.list method of the google calendar api via python.

```
service.acl().list(calendarId='primary').execute();
*** HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/acl?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

I'm using the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' as recommended in the documentation. Additionally, other API methods do work, for example service.calendarList

```
service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

What am I missing?

Here is the code I'm using based almost entirely on the sample they provide:

```
import sys

from oauth2client import client
from googleapiclient import sample_tools

def main(argv):
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'calendar', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
      # scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly')
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')

  try:
    page_token = None
    while True:
      calendar_list = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
      for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items']:
        print calendar_list_entry['summary']
      page_token = calendar_list.get('nextPageToken')
      service.acl().list(calendarId='primary').execute();
      if not page_token:
        break

  except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run'
      'the application to re-authorize.')

if __name__ == '__main__':

  main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Which kind of authentication are you using ? Do you use wide delegation authentication ? If yes, you need to verify that you have authorized the access of APIs for your sub account.

Comment: @erjoalgo Any idea as to why readonly access fails? I couldn't find read/write permissions being necessary for this being documented anywhere, but it doesn't work without them. I just want to view/list() the access control list -- not modify it.

Answer (score 3):

You might have to delete existing credentials, in the form of .json files. I had a similar "Insufficient permissions" problem, and I had to delete stored credentials. I had the additional problem that because of trying out some of Google's scripts in their tutorials, unknowingly I had credentials stored in a hidden .credentials folder in my home directory (users/home). Since they were hidden, I had to look for them through Terminal (on Mac), and delete them there. Once deleted, the problem was solved, since I could create new and proper credentials, suitable for the scope of my new script.

Comment: Thanks for indicating the location of the stored credentials to delete - I was able to go to my .credentials folder and delete the file from there.

Comment: Wow...Literally had no idea why anything wasn't working!! This fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your authentication.  Insufficent permissions means that you don't have access.

I can verify that the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` is enough to display [ACL.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list#auth) on the `primary` calendar.

Comment: "Something is wrong with your authentication". Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the location of "calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json" file and delete it. I used .NET example and I have to debug the following code the find exact location.

string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");

Then change scope as bellow and rebuild the solution.

string[] scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar};

You will notice that google will ask to confirm the access again.